# Compatibility of VC++ 6.0 on Window server 2016

Tags: visual-c++

We have developed VC++ 6.0 console application which is currently running as a service on Window server 2008 R2.

But now we want to compile and run the same service on Window server 2016.

Will VC++ 6.0 be compatible on this OS : window server 2016 ?

Regards
Amey

Comment: Is the program statically linked, not using any VC++ 6.0 specific DLL's? Then it would probably run. But you *really* should consider doing an upgrade of your IDE, it haven't been officially supported for well over a decade.

Comment: No DLL as such.. but when we compile the program we setup include , library and sourve file sections with respective paths like C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\MFC\INCLUDE
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\ATL\INCLUDE
C:\Program Files (x86)\MICROSOFT SDK\INCLUDE
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\INCLUDE

Comment: If you link dynamically, you'll need the VS6 runtime installed, but I don't think there are any reasons why it shouldn't work. That being said, you really should upgrade to the newest version.

Comment: Its client server application... client developed in VS 2005 and running on hand held terminal device and service is developed in VC 6.0 running o window server 2008 R2. HHT devices connects to this service using wifi. we need to run this service in window server 2016 and then HHT should connect to it.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz , you mean i cannt do VC 6 development on Window server 2016 ? nto event i can not compile it ?.... only i can run VC6 application ?